# stereographic projections find the function

Tags: calculus, functions

[image: an image]

The problem is in the image.  I need help.  I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the triangle depicted is isosceles, the angle of the triangle at the North Pole is $\frac{1}{2}(\pi - \varphi)$. Then, the triangle with corners at the North Pole and along the line at the points indicated by $0$ and $x$ has a right angle at $0$, and the shorter legs opposite and adjacent to the North Pole have length $x$ and $2R$ respectively, so using the definition of $\tan$ gives:

$$x = 2R \tan\left[\tfrac{1}{2}(\pi - \varphi)\right],$$

which we might also like to write as

$$x = 2R \cot\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\varphi\right).$$

There's a half-angle identity for cotangent, but I don't think it makes the formula any nicer or more usable.

Answer (score 1):

If the Cartesian co-ordinate of the point P is (y,z),then under stereographic projection  x will be z/(1-y).